# Can't Load Current location in Flutter application

Tags: google-maps, flutter, dart

I'm using geolocator plugin and getting current latitude and longitude but i can't load that in initstate of my Flutter Application.
It showing Render Error.

```
void initState() {
// TODO: implement initState
super.initState();
getCurrentLocation();

}

void getCurrentLocation() async {
var answer = await Geolocator().getCurrentPosition();
setState(() {
  latitude = answer.latitude;
  longitude = answer.longitude;
});
```

}

Map is Got updated with current location after some milli seconds but it showing these errors.
I/flutter (14143): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

I/flutter (14143): The following assertion was thrown building HomePage(dirty, state: _HomePageState#d55de):

I/flutter (14143): 'package:google_maps_flutter/src/location.dart': Failed assertion: line 17 pos 16: 'latitude !=

I/flutter (14143): null': is not true.

I/flutter (14143):

I/flutter (14143): Either the assertion indicates an error in the framework itself, or we should provide substantially

I/flutter (14143): more information in this error message to help you determine and fix the underlying cause.

I/flutter (14143): In either case, please report this assertion by filing a bug on GitHub:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Abbas.M suggestion i'm solving my problem using FutureBuilder Widget.

FutureBuilder Widget:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ek8ZPdWj4Qo

I'm declaring variable _future

```
Future<Position> _future;
```

I'm calling my async method in the initState

```
void initState() {
// TODO: implement initState
super.initState();
_future = getCurrentLocation();
}
```

Using FutureBuilder widget i solved my problem and i'm passing my async function return value to parameter of FutureBuilder widget.

This Condition if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) helps to find our async function completed and returned value or not. if it is in Done state then it means function completed and returned.

If that condition is not satisfied then it means async function is not completed so i'm using CircularProgressIndicator widget to notify user to understand app is loading.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text("Flutter Krish"),
    ),
    body: FutureBuilder(
        future: _future,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
            if (!snapshot.hasError) {
              print(snapshot.data.latitude);
              return Stack(children: <Widget>[
                GoogleMap(
                  initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
                      target: LatLng(
                          snapshot.data.latitude, snapshot.data.longitude),
                      zoom: 12.0),
                  onMapCreated: mapCreated,
                ),
                Positioned(
                  top: 30.0,
                  left: 15.0,
                  right: 15.0,
                  child: Container(
                    height: 50.0,
                    width: double.infinity,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                        color: Colors.white),
                    child: TextField(
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                          border: InputBorder.none,
                          hintText: 'Enter Address',
                          contentPadding:
                              EdgeInsets.only(top: 15.0, left: 15.0),
                          suffixIcon: IconButton(
                            icon: Icon(Icons.search),
                            onPressed: searchAndNavigate,
                            iconSize: 30.0,
                          )),
                      onChanged: (value) {
                        searchAddress = value;
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ]);
            }
          } else {
            return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          }
        }));
}

Future<Position> getCurrentLocation() async
{
var answer = await Geolocator().getCurrentPosition();
return answer;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I tried many ways until I found this way thanks to a kind person who helped on another flutter facebook group. Make sure in your pubspec.yaml you update location to the latest version

dependencies:
  location: ^2.3.5
Then change it to the following code:

```js
 
  LocationData _currentLocation;
  StreamSubscription<LocationData> _locationSubscription;

  var _locationService = new Location();
  String error;

  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    initPlatformState();

    _locationSubscription = _locationService
        .onLocationChanged()
        .listen((LocationData currentLocation) async {
      setState(() {
        _currentLocation = currentLocation;
      });
    });
  }

  void initPlatformState() async {
    try {
      _currentLocation = await _locationService.getLocation();


    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      if (e.code == 'PERMISSION_DENIED') {
        error = 'Permission denied';
      }else if(e.code == "PERMISSION_DENIED_NEVER_ASK"){
        error = 'Permission denied';
      }
      _currentLocation = null;
    }
 Run code snippetReturn to post
```

You may access longitude and latitude as

_currentLocation.longitude and _currentLocation.latitude

these will return double values. Also, there are more options available at https://pub.dev/packages/location#-readme-tab-

Comment: Thanks for your support bro, i solved my application error by using FutureBuilder widget.

Comment: could you post your solution here so that it might help the others

Answer (score 0):

I have almost no idea what's happening but based on the code since you have a .then, before the .then function happen your latitude and longitude are null, and when you have a .then the rest of your code is not awaiting for the future to be resolved. Try initializing the longitude and latitude to some value other than null in your init state so:

```
void initState() {
// TODO: implement initState
super.initState();
latitude = 0;
longitude = 0;
getCurrentLocation().then((k) {
  latitude = k.latitude;
  longitude = k.longitude;
  setState(() {});
  });
}
```

Comment: i tried like your suggestion but its loading for 0,0 only, and not updating current location. now i changed my code, now first my app screen showing error, after some millisecond its showing map with current location.

Comment: that's because you have to setstate again after the .then finishes

Comment: just add `setState(() {});` as the last line in the  .then method

Comment: Bro, I changed my code like your suggestion, but Map loading for initial value 0,0 and not updating current location in UI. but My code in question getting error initially but after some milliseconds, its updating current location in UI

Comment: The error you're getting initially is because the latitude and longitude are being used while they are set to 0. The error disappears because after a little while your getCurrentLocation() resolves and they have values instead of remaining at null. You should look into FutureBuilder if you want to avoid these stuff. check out [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ek8ZPdWj4Qo)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion brother. FutureBuilder widget helps me solve my application error.

Comment: It's my pleasure! Let me know if you need more help

Comment: Definitely Brother