# SharedPreference value null on startup

Tags: flutter, dart, sharedpreferences

There is a variable `pinEnable` which tells the app whether the user has set up a pin for the app. This is stored in `SharedPreferences`. My first page that comes in my app depends on it. Since the fetching operation is async, it just returns `null`.

the relevant code I used is given:-

`PinData` is just a class containing functions to set and get `pin` and `pinEnable`

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  bool pinEnable;
  PinData pinData = PinData();

  updatePinEnable() async {
    pinEnable = await pinData.getPinEnable();
    print(pinEnable);
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    updatePinEnable();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        theme: ThemeData(...),
        home: pinEnable == false ? MyTabbedHome() : PinCodePage());
  }
}
```

In the last code statement `pinEnable` is not false but it's null, therefore it returns `PinCodePage()`

Is there any way to fix this, or any ideas to get around this. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need stateful widget
,and this is a better solution using a `FutureBuilder` to return the correct widget only when the async process is completed:

**Edit:** edited the code to address fact that you are not setting initial value in shared prefs

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  PinData pinData = PinData();

  Future<bool> isPinEnabled() async => pinData.getPinEnable();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<bool>(
        future: isPinEnabled(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<bool> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return CircularProgressIndicator();
          }
          else if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return snapshot.data ?
              PinScreen() //if true returned from shared prefs go to pin screen
                  :
              HomeScreen(); //if false returned from shared prefs go to home screen
            }
            else {
              return HomeScreen(); //if null returned from shared prefs go to home screen
            }
          }
        }
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: It didn't work. it's just returning the `CircularProgressIndicator();`  just the circle nothing else.

Comment: What is the intial value stored in shared prefs of the boolean when you initialize it ,is it false?or null?

Comment: I figured it out. Thanks for the hint 'FutureBuilder' it got me thinking. Your method is correct the problem was that we had to run the `pinData.getPinEnable()' in the `initState` and save it in a variable, this variable is what we shuold put in the `future: ` attribute. For this, I made it a stateful widget.  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57019109/future-builder-is-not-getting-data). THANKS!!  Future builder helped me!

Comment: @decoratorDust please see the edited answer it now solves your problem bcz you are not initializing the variable to false in shared prefs

Comment: @decoratorDust you don't need a stateful widget again,FutureBuilder and StatelessWidget are enough