# Why is my Future Builder not receiving connection?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am building an app that keeps track of what meals you ate today. It is geared towards people with dementia so they know which meals they already ate. My future builder is not working, but the code runs. All I receive is a blank screen with the Circular Progress Bar, where instead there should be three dismissible, one labeled breakfast, one lunch, and one dinner.

I am using shared_preferences to persist whether the user dismissed a meal, however I can't seem to figure out what is the problem with my code. Can somebody please help me? I've pasted the code below.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'dart:async';

class HomeLeft extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeLeftState createState() => _HomeLeftState();
}

class _HomeLeftState extends State<HomeLeft> {
  List<Icon> iconList = [Icon(Icons.free_breakfast), Icon(Icons.fastfood), Icon(Icons.local_dining)];
  List initialList = List();


  changeList() async{
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    List meals = (prefs.getStringList('meals') ?? ['Breakfast', 'Lunch', 'Dinner']);
    meals.removeLast();
    List<String> _meals;
    _meals = meals.map((s) => s as String).toList();
    print(meals);
    await prefs.setStringList('meals', _meals);
  }

  Future getInitial() async{
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    List initial = (prefs.getStringList('meals') ?? ['Breakfast', 'Lunch', 'Dinner']);
    setState(() {
      initialList = initial;
    });
    return initial;
  }

  change(){
    changeList();
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body:
      FutureBuilder(
          future: getInitial(),
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
            switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
              case ConnectionState.waiting:
                return Center(child:
                CircularProgressIndicator());
              default:
                if (snapshot.hasError) {
                  return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
                } else {
                  return ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: initialList.length,
                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                        return Dismissible(
                          onDismissed: change(),
                          key: Key(index.toString()),
                          child: ListTile(
                            title: Text(initialList[index]),
                            leading: iconList[index],
                          ),
                          background: Container(
                            color: Colors.green,
                            child: Padding(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
                              child: Row(
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  Icon(
                                    Icons.done,
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                  )
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        );
                      }
                    );
                  }
               }
              }
            )
          );
        }
      }
```

How can I implement what I am trying to accomplish? The three dismissibles should only go away when the user swipes it I am trying to persist the meals left in the day, so when the user opens the app again after closing it, only two dismissible meals will pop up. Also, how would I go about to resetting the three every new day?

If someone could help me with this problem that would be absolutely terrific.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling async method in inside FutureBuilder Widget. call that function inside initState method and get that return value in one varible and use that in FutureBuilder Widget.

**Problem:**
Calling function directly in FutureBuilder then FutureBuilder will call that function again and again to check for the value. so you can't get the value.

**Solution:**
Assign that function in one variable and assign that variable to FutureBuilder will check that variable alone and not going to call that function anymore.

[Check this link for more understanding](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/27847#issuecomment-462868299)

[Similar Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56875205/cant-load-current-location-in-flutter-application)

```
Future futureData;

@override
void initState() {
  // TODO: implement initState
  super.initState();
  futureData = getInitial();
}

FutureBuilder(
  future: futureData,
  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {})
```